# Quotient Maps Composition

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Composition of quotient maps is a quotient map

My attempt:

Let $q_1:X\rightarrow Y$, $q_2:Y\rightarrow Z$ be quotient maps. I will show that $q_2\circ q_1$ is a quotient map. Since the composition of surjections is a surjection, the composition is a surjection. Let $U$ be open in $Z$. So $q_2^{-1}(U)$ is open in $Y$ and since $q_1$ is continuous, $q_1^{-1}(q_2^{-1}(U))$ is open in $X$. This implies that $(q_2\circ q_1)^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Hence $Z$ admits the quotient topology, so $q_2\circ q_1$ is a quotient map.

Is my proof correct and complete? (Please answer this)

Comment: All you did was prove the composition of two continuous functions is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you’re proving the wrong direction and reproving that the composition of continuous maps is continuous. So we now know that $q_2 \circ q_1 $ is continuous and indeed onto.

To see the quotient map property, we assume that $O \subseteq Z$ is such that $(q_2 \circ q_1)^{-1}[O]$ is open. Note then again that

$$(q_2 \circ q_1)^{-1}[O]=q_1^{-1}[q_2^{-1}[O]] \text{ is open}$$

And as $q_1$ is quotient we conclude that

$$q_2^{-1}[O] \text{ is open}$$ and finally, as $q_2$ is quotient, we conclude that $O$ is open as required.